# MS-DOS "plugin" system?

Tags: windows, batch-file, plugins, cmd, system

Creating a program called Joker.cmd (https://github.com/nightmare-dll/Joker/), and it's basically done. Was basically me testing out github at first and turned into something I wouldn't mind fully releasing.

It's basically done, so I would love to implement a user plugin system. Dir tree is as of rightnow (not synced on github);

```
 data/
  -config.cmd
 plugins/
  - test1.cmd
  - test2.cmd
 joker.cmd
```

So then joker.cmd would list both "test1.cmd" and "test2.cmd" and have a

```
 set /p plugin=Plugin name; 
 start %plugin%.cmd
```

and then run the specified plugin.
The only issue is how would I get joker.cmd to list only files ending in either .cmd or .bat?

Comment: `dir /b plugins\*.cmd plugins\*.bat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How would I get joker.cmd to list only files ending in either .cmd or .bat?

Add the following lines to joker.cmd to run the plugins automatically:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b plugins\*.cmd plugins\*.bat') do (
  start "" %%f
  )
```

Add the following lines to joker.cmd to prompt for the plugin to run:

```
dir /b plugins\*.cmd plugins\*.bat
set /p plugin=Plugin name: 
start "" plugins\%plugin%
```

Note:

> - Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`
>
>   According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Source [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).